# setting up a tablelayout

Tags: java, android, android-tablelayout

I am trying to build a list application for now and I need to align both the button and the text in the same row but as I am extremely new to android studio and Java I am having trouble. any guides I have found are out of date 
my code is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:strechColumns="1">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:baselineAligned="false">

        <TextView

            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Job 1"
            />

    </TableRow>

    <ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:onClick=""
    android:text="test text"
    />
</TableLayout>
```

any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try below code inside  tag:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  >
        <TextView
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:text="Job 1"
        />
        <ToggleButton
          android:id="@+id/button1"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:onClick=""
          android:text="test text"
        />
     />
```

Comment: thanks for this but I think I'm going to try a different approach using tables seems to be the wrong way to go about this

Answer (score 0):

Putting your **ToggleButton** in `TableRow` will put your items in same row.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="1"
android:strechColumns="1">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:baselineAligned="false">

        <TextView

            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Job 1"/>

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="test text"/>

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Other then that If you can achieve same with using **List/RecyclerView Adapter** if you only need two elements in row, 
Using  **List/RecyclerView** is simple approach then TableView. In your Adapter use following XML code for item iterations

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView    
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/toggleButton"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/toggleButton"
        android:layout_alignParentleft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:text="test "/>

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
  </RelativeLayout>
```